# Should mutations always use POST?

Tags: http, post, get, xss, http-method

Philosophically, I am accustomed to always using GET for HTTP requests that do not alter state, and POST for requests that do.  However, lately I have run into some difficulties with this that have caused me to make exceptions.  I was curious if there is any non-philosophical downside to using the wrong HTTP verbs, such as security concerns like cross-site attacks.

#### Exception #1

I wanted to trigger a download of a requested list of files dynamically packaged into an archive.  However, the list of files could grow so large that, when encoded as querystring parameters in the URL, they exceeded the url length limit in Internet Explorer.  To work around this, I ended up triggering the download with a POST.

#### Exception #2

There is a button that is always displayed, regardless of whether you are logged in or not, but it can only alter state if you are logged in.  If you press it when you are not logged in, you are taken to the login page with a querystring parameter indicating the place you were intending to go next.  When you log in, it redirects you there to complete your action.  However, the redirect can only generate a GET, not a POST.  So we have allowed GETs to alter state in this situation.

Are there any exploits or downsides to these exceptions?  Do these allow any cross-site request forgery scenarios that cannot be prevented by checking the referer header?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question in subject: Yes

Exception #1: A GET request can have a body. You don't have to put everything in the URL

Exception #2: Alter the form to use GET when not logged in and POST if logged in.

Using referer is not recommended. There have been all sorts of workarounds, and some corporate software strip it for privacy concerns.
I highly recommend a token based approach to CSRF-mitigation.